# What is this in my electrical box? Can I attach my ground wire onto this screw? Will it be securely grounded?

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image]

I am trying to wire a dimmer in an old outlet box and need to attach a ground. All other holes are too big or small, except the two that are being occupied by what looks like a wire clamp. Is it safe to attach my ground wire to this clamp? Thanks for your help!

Comment: looks more like a strain relief. You can also attach ground directly to the switch/outlet you will be putting into the box (pigtail as needed)

Comment: look for where the other ground wires are connected to the box.

Comment: Can you post a photo looking squarely into the back of the box please?

Answer (score 2):

That screw holds down the cable clamp, which is anchoring your BX cables into the box.  I have seen it used for grounds but it's not ideal at all.

Push the wires around in the back of the box and look for a hole that is somewhat smaller than the others.   This may be tapped #10-32, if so it is specifically for a ground screw.   They sell #10-32 ground screws plated green, either with or without integrated pigtails.

Answer (score 0):

That type of screw almost assuredly has a machine thread.  It therefor would provide an adequate ground as long as the box itself is grounded properly.

Comment: That screw works in conjunction with the clamp in the box that secures the BX cable to the box.